# Knockout-Kendo Js Databound Event

Tags: knockout-kendo

Can anyone tell me why when attaching to the Databound event for any Knockout-Kendo widget, this event always fires twice. Or has anyone else encountered this behavior. Thank you.

Comment: got the same issue here